# MYSQL query check how many person owns items

Tags: mysql, sql

I want to check if any person owns every single item in my list.
(Or display what person owns hogy many items)

Table name: item
Fields: id (unique), person_id, and item_id

The item_ids what I looking for is 1,2,3 to be easy.

Example data in the item table
112, 41, 1
313, 50, 1
453, 50, 2
647, 50, 3
440, 55, 2
451, 66, 2
453, 66, 3
453, 66, 3
647, 66, 1

As you see person 50 and 66 owns all of 1,2,3 items. (No problem is he have duplicate)
The query should return how many they have like tihs:
66(person), 4(pcs)
50(person), 3(pcs)
41(person), 1(pcs)
55(person), 1(pcs)
(It doesn't matter if it displays the 1-1pcs or not what is under 3)

Can someone help me write a query what return this result?

Comment: Note that your stated question and your desired result differ in intent.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you just looking for `in` and `group by`?

```
select person, count(*) as num_items
from t
where item in (1, 2, 3)
group by person
order by num_items desc;
```

Comment: Just to observe, while it accords with the desired result, this query doesn't satisfy the criteria stated within the title.

Comment: @radocaw . . . I suspect the issue was a language issue and the OP meant "any", not "all".